# Meaning of numbers in left column of output pane in Visual Studio when building

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, build

I've wondered for years as to what is the meaning of numbers in the left column of the output pane in Visual Studio when doing a build.  The generally increase as each project in the solution gets built, but they also jump around as well.  For example:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: MyCompany.MyProject1, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
2>------ Rebuild All started: Project: MyCompany.MyProject2, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
3>------ Rebuild All started: Project: MyCompany.MyProject3, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
4>------ Rebuild All started: Project: MyCompany.MyProject4, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
4>C:\SourcePath\MyApplication\MyNamespace\Views\MyFeature\MyCompany.MyProject2.csproj(172,3): warning MSB4011: "C:\MyPath1.CSharp.targets" cannot be imported again. It was already imported at "C:\MyPath2\MyCompany.Build.CustomAfterMicrosoftCSharpTargets.props (41,5)". This is most likely a build authoring error. This subsequent import will be ignored. 
4>  Restoring NuGet packages...
4>  To prevent NuGet from downloading packages during build, open the Visual Studio Options dialog, click on the Package Manager node and uncheck 'Allow NuGet to download missing packages'.
4>  Feeds used:
4>    C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache
4>    C:\Users\MyUser\.nuget\packages\
4>    https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
4>    http://nuget.MyCompany.com/nuget/api/v2/
4>    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\
4>  
4>  All packages listed in MyPath5\packages.config are already installed.
4>  MyCompany.MyProject4 -> MyPath6\MyCompany.MyProject4.dll
5>------ Rebuild All started: Project: MyCompany.MyNamespace.This.Something, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
5>  MyCompany.MyNamespace.This.Something -> C:\SourcePath\MyApplication\MyNamespace\ThisLayer\Something\bin\Debug\MyCompany.MyNamespace.This.Something.dll
3>C:\SourcePath\MyApplication\MyNamespace\Views\MyFeature\MyCompany.MyProject2.csproj(172,3): warning MSB4011: "C:\MyPath1.CSharp.targets" cannot be imported again. It was already imported at "C:\MyPath2\MyCompany.Build.CustomAfterMicrosoftCSharpTargets.props (41,5)". This is most likely a build authoring error. This subsequent import will be ignored. 
3>  Restoring NuGet packages...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the start of a build Visual Studio assigns a unique number for each of the projects that you want to build until a maximum number is reached that I'll explain in a second. In your case these are the first four lines you are seeing: `X>------ Rebuild All started`

Now VS (with its companion MSBuild) tries to resolve the dependencies between your projects. Then it groups the projects into units that have to be built sequentially one after another because they are depending on each other. But the groups themselves don't have any dependencies among them and thus can compile in parallel without affecting each other.

The maximum number of parallel builds can be changed in VS under `Tools --> Options --> Project and Solutions --> Build and Run --> maximum number of parallel project builds`. The default value in my case are 4 parallel builds, but it's [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cyhcc7zc.aspx) that the individual default is the number of your CPU cores, that it only affects C# and C++ projects and that the maximum number currently is 32. (I don't know if that means logical or physical cores but logical cores would make the most sense to me.)

Each number at the beginning of every line in the output window now belongs to the build progress of the project that has been assigned to this number.

So in your case `MyCompany.MyProject4` is (most likely purely random) built first and all lines starting with `4>` belong to that project. When it has finished VS decides to use this free slot and gets another project `MyCompany.MyNamespace.This.Something` into the build process to which it assigns the number `5>`.

It starts to build this project but then all of a sudden the build of project `MyCompany.MyProject3` with the number `3>` is finally making some progress and prints its build messages.

So the shuffling of the numbers is actually the result of four parallel threads that are printing their outputs as they happen. In fact, each of these threads is actually a separate process of MSBuild.exe which you can see in Windows Task Manager.

If all of your projects would have exactly one other project dependency (and each project is referenced only once) then you'll never see a parallel build if you build them together because there's nothing there that can safely be done at the same time. (You can't depend on something that hasn't been built yet.)

You can find a bit more detailed information about the parallel build in the [documentation of Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383805.aspx) and in the [documentation of MSBuild](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb651793.aspx).